# Alternative Tool or Machine to practice Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, hortonworks-data-platform

Can you please help me with alternative options to practice Hadoop. I tried to use Quick Start CDH to run on VMWare but due to my system limitations I couldn't make use of this option. My system doesnt support 64 bit guest OS nor the BIOs has virtualization option to enable or disable it. One option I know is HortOnWorks, but sure whether it can resolve the my issue.

Thanks and Regards,
cool

Comment: No one has the answer/solution to above issue !!!! Does everyone bought new system to practice Hadoop. Cant I experiment with hadoop technologies using the following system configuration. OS Windows 8.1 64 bit. Processor type - Intel  Core 2 Duo Processor T6400
* 2.0 GHz, 2 MB L2 Cache, 800 MHz FSB
Standard memory - 4096 MB
Memory - DDR2 800 MHz
Memory layout - (2 x 2048 MB)
Maximum memory - Supports up to 8 GB DDR2 memory.

Comment: Even there is hortonworks but it also gives service for one month. what after one month? I am trying to find way so that I dont have to keep on working on installation of Hadoop, mine focus is on practising Hadoop.